# Native App or PhoneGap or appcelerator or something else?

Tags: iphone, android, cordova, appcelerator

I'm very new to mobile app, and having difficulty finding the right direction to move ahead with our current project. I hope to receive some insights, suggestions from the experts here based on your experience.

Below are are main features our project needs:
1. Get user current GPS location and send to our server (and receive a list of location to display)

1. Take picture and perhaps even video with phone camera (if available) then store and send to our server when the users want to (in case they do not have free wifi at the mean time, they may decide to send later)
2. Join chat rooms (hosted on our server)
3. Store certain info (location info such as address/fone etc and chat logs for offline usage)

We want to support iphone and android first, budget is also a big concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the native app approach, it means you will have to code separately for both android and iphone platforms.
Considering your budget concerns, PhoneGap and Appcelerator should work for you. Both are powerful platforms. But before choosing either of these, consider a few points about each of them.

If you choose phone gap, you will be coding in HTML, css and javascript. Also you will be building a mobile web application.

If you choose appcelerator titanium, you will require only javascript skills to develop app and the look and feel you get will be closer to the native app. There might be a slight performance delay with the android build of it as compared to iphone, which is acceptable in most cases.First go through its demo (Kitchensink project), then decide if this platform suits you.

Comment: I decided to do this in the end: Native app for Android and Iphone, and simplified version of html web app as well. This way we can cover lots of ground. Hope there will come a day where only web app is enough